# How can I identify the id of a button sending values to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm working with a MySQL database and I display some records using PHP. I'm adding a button to each row so the user can click on it and open a new div (maina) based in the selection.

The PHP script will generate the next HTML code:

```
<tr><td>Area1</td><td>Dept1</td><td><button class="btn btn-alert" id="edita" value="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Area2</td><td>Dept2</td><td><button class="btn btn-alert" id="edita" value="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Area3</td><td>Dept3</td><td><button class="btn btn-alert" id="edita" value="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>
```

And so on... I'm trying to use the following jQuery code to get the value of the clicked button:

```
$("#edita").on( "click", function() {
    var regid = $("#edita").val();
    $("#maina").load('hello.php',{"reg_id":regid}, function(response, status, xhr){
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Error!, Something went wrong: ";
            $("#maina").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine for the first record, it displays the information contained in hello.php and gets the value from the first button; but when I click on the other buttons nothing happens, it doesn't even open the *maina* div (hello.php must be displayed in maina and show different information based on the button's value).

I was wondering in using a different ID assigned dinamically by PHP EG *edita1*, *edita2*... *editan* but I don't know how to call them from the jQuery code without writing a block of code for each button.

Is there a solution for my issue? Can you help me please?

Comment: why not use data-values? By the way, Never have multiple elements with the same `id`. Why not reference each of the buttons with a class name, like `$(".btn")` and get their values through their Id (use `this`), (ex. `$(".btn").click(function(){ alert(this.id); });` )

Comment: Multiple elements with identical `id`s are not valid HTML and any javascript operating on those elements is susceptible to undefined behavior.   Use `class` if you want to target multiple elements with an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

When inside the click event you can refer to the target element as 'this' so the code becomes:

```
 var regid = $(this).val();
```

The method you are using at the moment selects all buttons with id edita and the .val() will always pick the first value it finds.

Also, I would advise using different IDs for each button for the sake of producing valid html, and then use a class or name attribute to identify them in the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same id for all buttons. This could cause issues.
Use class selector. Then use 'this' keyword to get the data. eg

```js
<script>
$(".edita").on( "click", function() {
    var regid = $(this).val();
    alert(regid);
    /*$("#maina").load('hello.php',{"reg_id":regid}, function(response, status, xhr){
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Error!, Something went wrong: ";
            $("#maina").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });*/
});
</script>
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Area1</td><td>Dept1</td><td><button class="btn btn-alert edita" id="edita" value="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Area2</td><td>Dept2</td><td><button class="btn btn-alert edita" id="edita" value="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>
<tr><td>Area3</td><td>Dept3</td><td><button class="btn btn-alert edita" id="edita" value="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Let me know if it will work